# PHP Dynamically accessing an associative array

Tags: php, associative-array, variable-variables

EDITED FROM ORIGINAL THAT HAD IMPLIED ONLY 1 ACCESS

If I have an array that contains x number of arrays, each of the form

```
array('country' => array('city' => array('postcode' => value)))
```

and another array that might be

```
array('country', 'city', 'postcode') or array('country', 'city')
```

depending on what I need to retrieve, how do I use the second array to identify the index levels into the first array and then access it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why not doing a simple loop?

Comment: I would almost call that a: `stealth edit`! Please mark it as an *EDIT* if you extend your question! And if the edit is a completely new question make a new on!

Comment: It's not a completely new question. It was edited to show that it has to be done multiple times.

Comment: sorry but this edit is the same of your original question, you can't have more than 1 value inside `$array['capital']['city']['postcode']` as I have explained in comments

Comment: No, you can't. But that wasn't the point. I was simply saying that if the array contains 20 countries, do I need to iterate again and again based on the indexes for each of the 20, or is there a way to assemble the indexes into a variable variable and access each of the 20 using it and not iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I apologize for not having expressed my question more clearly, originally, but I got it to work as I was hoping, with a variable variable, as follows:

```
$keystring = '';
foreach ($keys as $key) {
  $keystring .= "['$key']";
}
```

Then iterate the main array, for each of the country entries in it, and access the desired value as:

```
eval('$value = $entry' . "$keystring;");
```

Answer (score 1):

By nesting references with `$cur = &$cur[$v];` you can read and modify the original value:
Live example on ide1: http://ideone.com/xtmrr8

```
$array = array('x' => array('y' => array('z' => 20)));
$keys = array('x', 'y', 'z');

// Start nesting new keys
$cur = &$array;
foreach($keys as $v){
    $cur = &$cur[$v];
}

echo $cur;  // prints 20
$cur = 30;  // modify $array['x']['y']['z']
```

Comment: I think that's the best possible answer! Very nice explained and good comments! Deserves an upvotes :D

Comment: Let me add one more consideration. If I have 20 of $array, say each being a country, and given $keys, I need to access each of the 20 in the same way, is there a way to do it without iterating each?

Comment: I don't know if that is a different question or is it related. Anyway if this answer helped you consider to +1 it

Comment: Same question. Just trying to consider efficiency. If my keys are ('capital','city','postcode']) and I want the postcode in each of 20 countries, once I determine the keys, is iterating as such what I should do? Could be, that there is no way to do it as a variable variable (like ${$myarray}{['x']['y']['z']} or something to that effect. Just making sure.

Comment: how can you have 20 countries if you are accesing an exact item in your array `$array['capital']['city']['postcode']` ? Anyway I think this is another question open a new question

Comment: ok, sorry. I've asked it more clearly this time, I think. If there is NOT a way to access each of them, having determined the keys, without iterating, then of course I'll select your current answer.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array of indexes, traveling down the initial array step by step until you reach the end of the index array.

```
$array1 = array('x' => array('y' => array('z' => 20)));
$keys = array('x', 'y', 'z');
$array_data = &$array1;
foreach($keys as $key){
    $array_data = &$array_data[$key];
}
echo $array_data;
```

Comment: this will create a new copy of that value

Comment: Edited to pass by reference